# Hard time to understand building 250 V HV from 3.3 V and problem with transformer

Tags: transformer, high-voltage, transient

I have built PicoEMP device ( https://github.com/newaetech/chipshouter-picoemp )  device which diagram I'm attaching:
[image: Schematics]

It's basic role is to built ~250 V voltage from 3.3V GPIO and release it through the coil in short time to generate EM pulse.

The coil is **J1** and the HV charge is mainly in **C3**.

The high voltage builds in 2-3 seconds when 3.3 V signal with 2500 Hz frequency and ~ 1% duty cycle signal is provided on **HVPWM** input. Then it's intended to be released with sort ~10 us 3.3 V pulse on **HVPULSE** input. Unfortunately this doesn't happen on board I've built. I can release charge only with **SW3** switch which discharges it over **R1**, **R2** resistors.
I'm wondering what should happen on both **T2** windings when **HVPULSE** is served with 10 us 3.3 V pulse and what exactly happens in HV part around **D7** that time.

Comment: Have you looked at the various signals with a scope? Is enough gate drive getting to Q2?

Comment: Ensure polarity of T2 winding is correct. Swapping the polarity won't hurt. || HVPULSE high drives Q4 on discharges C5 via T2 primary - produces pulse in T2 secondary drives Q2 gate on.

Comment: Polarity is ok T1 and T2 are same elements and the dot on package is on both on primary side. Also HV is present on secondary windings of T2 when PWM signal is on. I bet this would fry low voltage part in such case.  What I'm missing is what is the exact expected low voltage signal on T1 and how it sums on secondary windows side with existing high voltage to drive the Q2. I bet D7 diode has its role in this but trying to understand this.  I have oscope outputs but unable to attach those in comment. 
When HVPULSE is on after some  harmonics the Q4 output towards T2 is 1.0V when HVP 3.1V

Comment: Please post oscillograms.

Comment: @nusch  You said " I'm wondering what should happen on both T2 windings when HVPULSE is served with 10 us 3.3 V pulse and what exactly happens in HV part around D7 that time." --> My answer answers that question explicitly. Does t make sense to you, and does it tell you what you want to know? || If D7 polarity is reversed it will not work. THIS IS A MAJOR POTENTIAL REASON FOR NOT WORKING.  ||If EITHER T2 primary or secondary is reversed it will not work. || IOf BOTH T2 primary and secondary are reversed it should still work.

Answer (score 2):

**Ensure** polarity of T2 winding is correct.
The two transformers have opposite output polarity connections.
Swapping the polarity won't hurt.

Operation:

HVPULSE high drives Q4 on
discharges C5 via T2 primary
produces pulse in T2 secondary
drives Q2 gate on.

Note how T1 and T2 have opposite polarity outputs for positive out. This is because T1 is used as a flyback transformer. A ~= 3.3V pulse is applied and then removed. The output goes high on the OFF cycle.

The HV on T2 output is from T1 rectified.

On T2 turn-on, as above, a positive 3V pulse is applied to T2:4-1 causing a positive pulse to be output on T2:3-2.
Note sense on the above connections.
If you swap connections for either side it will not work.

T2 datasheet [here](https://product.tdk.com/en/search/transformer/transformer/step-up/info?part_no=ATB322524-0110-T000).
Step up ratio is 10.2:1 so you get ABOUT 30V pulse out.

These is clamped by zener D7 to ~ 18V.
This is applied to the gate of IGBT Q2.
Q2 datasheet [here](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/igbt/rgt16bm65d-e.pdf).